# How can I have my Linq select return something different based on a parameter of my method?

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
var options = xxx
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = ((int) Enum.ToObject(t, x)).ToString(),
        Text = Regex.Replace(x.ToString(), "([A-Z])", " $1").Trim()
    });
```

This is part of a method that's called like this:

```
GetSpacedOptions(bool zeroPad = false)
```

How can I make it so if the zeroPad is set to true then instead of returning 1,2,3,4,5 etc  that it returns "01","02" etc as the value in the select? If zeroPad is set to default or false then it needs to return 1,2 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I got the question right but here is one way to do it.

```
string numberFormat = zeroPad ? "D2" : "g";
...
Value = ((int) Enum.ToObject(t, x)).ToString(numberFormat),
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
var options = xxx 
.Select(x => new SelectListItem 
{ 
    Value = zeroPad ? ((int) Enum.ToObject(t, x)).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')
        : ((int) Enum.ToObject(t, x)).ToString(), 
    Text = Regex.Replace(x.ToString(), "([A-Z])", " $1").Trim() 
});
```

The trick to this is the `PadLeft` method. Note that the first argument is the total length of the string, so if `(int)Enum.ToObject(t, x)` returns a value in double (or more) figures, you may need to adjust the total length to something more suitable depending on how these larger values should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
private void GetSpacedOptions(bool zeroPad = false)
{
    string str = "";
    if(zeropad)
    {
        str = //
    }
    else
    {
        str = //
    }

    //Then use str in code
    var options = //
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand your answer. What I need to do is to change this: Value = ((int) Enum.ToObject(t, x)).ToString(), to something that returns a 2 digit 0 padded string if zeroPad is set to true.